# Kafka how to consume multiple topic parallel

Tags: apache-kafka, consumer, kafka-consumer-api

I have more than one topic and the message coming from each topic have different behavior. So I have to treat each message in a different manner. So I have differentiate message and its topic from Kafka stream. Is there any solution for this and I expect code snippet as an example. Thanks for any suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to consume from different kafka topics just go for [Consumer group or High Level consumer](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/Consumer+Group+Example) .. you can run different consumer group per topics